# Como pegar setar/pegar objeto no localstorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localstorage

Estou enviando um objeto do JSON para o `localStorage`:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('tarefa',aux);
```

E tento pegar esse objeto em outro controller assim:

```
$scope.tarefa=window.localStorage.getItem('tarefa')
```

Porém, ao mostrar no console esse `$scope.tarefa.id` (propriedade do objeto passado) dá `undefined`. Isso para essa propriedade ou para qualquer outra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acontece que só é possível salvar pares de **chave/valor** no *localStorage*/*sessionStorage*.

Então, ao tentar salvar um objeto como o valor da chave **`tarefa`** o que é salvo é a string `"[object Object]"`.

Se quiser testar, tente fazer um `console.log`, dessa forma

```
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('tarefa'));
```

A saída será

> "[object Object]"

---

É possível resolver isso convertendo o objeto para JSON antes de salvá-lo no *localStorage*.

```
// Cria um json a partir do objeto "aux" 
var jsonAux = JSON.stringify(aux);

// "Seta" este json no localStorage
window.localStorage.setItem('tarefa', jsonAux);

// Recupera o json do localStorage
var jsonTarefa = window.localStorage.getItem('tarefa');

// Converte este json para objeto
var tarefa = JSON.parse(jsonTarefa);

console.log(tarefa.id);
```